# Script stopping without errors after await Promise.all(...)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, centos8

So I ran into something really weird, I'm creating in a loop around 10 promises and adding them to an array but after the await Promise.all() the application exits without error in some cases.

I cannot share the original code but the code bellow has the same issue when ran in CentoOS 8 with nodejs: `nodejs.x86_64 1:10.21.0-3.module_el8.2.0+391+8da3adc6`

```
const shell = require("shelljs");
require('events').defaultMaxListeners = 15;

const run = async () => {
    await foo(DATA);
    console.log("Logging1"); // Get's printed
    await foo(OTHER_DATA_1);
    console.log("Logging2"); // Get's printed
    await foo(OTHER_DATA_2); // Usually at this level is where I no longer see the last log line
    // Here is also where the script exists without error (I've attached process.onExit and beforeExit but both print code 0
    console.log("More logging"); // Never get's printed
}

const foo = async (allData) => {
    let promises = [];
    for (const data of allData) {
        const command = "ecs-cli ....."; // An AWS ECS command (takes around ~1 minute)
        const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const cmdChildProcess = shell.exec(command, { silent: false, async: true });
            cmdChildProcess.on("close", (code) => {
                if (code === 0) {
                    const someData = doSomething(data);
                    console.log("Success!"); // Get's called
                    resolve(someData);
                } else {
                    console.error(`Process forcibly exited with code ${code}`); // Haven't seen this log line
                    reject(code);
                }
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error); // Haven't seen this get called either
        });
        promises.push(myPromise);
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log("I'm done with all the promises"); // Get's processed first couple of times
}

run();
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if it's because I've increased the listenerMaxCount.
Before increasing it I was doing something like:

```
let promises = [];

...
//loop
promises.push(myPromise);
if(promises.length >= 6) {
    await Promise.all(promises);
    promises = [];
}
...
```

But this made no difference the same issue was occurring.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Maybe yo can add a  `setTimeout(()=>reject("timeout"), 50000)` to force a reject after some time

Comment: oh ... try `run().then(() => console.log('fini'));` - I seem to recall that node.js doesn't give a crap about pending promises before exiting

Comment: @Sarabadu - read the code .... the command *takes around 1 minute* - why would you force reject after 50 seconds :p

Comment: @Bravo you are right `setTimeout(()=>reject("timeout"), 120000)`  its better but, also is not a nice solution, i will use it just for test.
and would be nice to take a look if `ecs-cli` command can prompt waiting for user interaction or confirm some action.

Comment: @Sarabadu - I doubt it's anything to do with Promises not getting finalised - it's node.js behaviour - it simply isn't waiting for the promises before exiting - I've had that happen to me

Comment: @Bravo weirdly enough Promise.all(...).run().then(....) makes ir worse :p now it finishes after the very first array of promises and doesn't continue.

Comment: @Bravo node.js waits for all promise callbacks that are scheduled. If they never got scheduled, that means the events that you expected to resolve the promise were never fired, and node.js exited because there were no pending *event* listeners.

Comment: What does `listenerMaxCount` have to do with this? There's no event emitter in your code on which you'd register too many listeners.

Comment: I was getting a warning/error when creating more than 10 promises (I was creating 12 in the loop) and that's what I found to remove that warning and allow up to 15 promises simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the issue although I'm still not a 100% sure why it's an issue.

But basically if I do the following it works:

```
 for (const data of allData) {
        const command = "ecs-cli ....."; // An AWS ECS command (takes around ~1 minute)
        const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const cmdChildProcess = shell.exec(command, { silent: false, async: true });
            cmdChildProcess.on("close", (code) => {
                if (code === 0) {
                    resolve({});
                } else {
                    console.error(`Process forcibly exited with code ${code}`); // Haven't seen this log line
                    reject(code);
                }
            });
        }).then((data) => {
              doSomething(data); // Noy async
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error); // Haven't seen this get called either
        });
        promises.push(myPromise);
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
```

As shown above basically all I did was removed the `doSomething(data)` from the `onClose` event and chained it as a resolution to the promise with `then()` and that seems to now work.

Comment: What is the return value of `doSomething`? Did it maybe throw exceptions?

Comment: I never saw an exception and it's a success or failed message but no exceptions (it calls AWS through their SDK)